# Generate the facebook signature using my applications secret key?

Tags: session, facebook, signature

When you build a website with "facebook connect" and you log into facebook with your username and password, facebook then sets a session on your website.

In that session is a generated "signature"

This signature is created by combining the data of your "application secret" that only you and Facebook know, and the result MD5 hashed.

I need the algorithm used to generate that signature so that I can recreate it and make sure it matches the one signature created by facebook.

```
if($_SESSION['facebookSignature'] == reGeneratedSignature){
   // save to database
}else{
  // go away I don't trust you
}
```

This way I can validate the user and I don't need to make unnecessary calls to Facebook and alow the user to continue to use the website.

Comment: Essentially Im trying to do this:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Verifying_The_Signature

but it does not work for me as Im using this: 

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib-alpha.FB

Answer (score 0):

The Verifying The Signature link is the way to go, so that should be working for you.

Have a look at the source code for [FBConnectAuth](http://fbconnectauth.codeplex.com/), it does what you want, and is generic so that it will adapt to any new FB Connect cookies that may appear - so hopefully that will adapt to the new JS library.

Hope that helps,

Adam

Comment: Actually I got all the info I needed here:
http://wiki.github.com/facebook/connect-js/faq

Thanks Adam

Comment: Great, I think I'm going to amend FBConnectAuth so that it will work with the new cookie format... Adam

Answer (score 0):

Reconstructing the signature created by Facebook is rather simple. You just need to append all `key=value` pairs, then append your private key, and finally compute the MD5 hash of the resulting string.

More details on how the signature is constructed can be found on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324444/is-auth-token-and-sig-the-same-thing-in-facebook-api/3324546#3324546).

Facebook has provided a PHP example of how to do reconstruct the sig [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login) in the Single Sign-On section.

I have written a [blog post](http://vombat.tumblr.com/post/835536630/ruby-version-of-facebooks-get-facebook-cookie-in-php) doing exactly the same, but in Ruby instead.